# JavaScript: Insert elements into array for every n elements

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert element into 2nd and 9th position of an array for every 10 elements and the length of array can be vary.
I tried to use mod but the element will be inserted multiple time within 10 elements.

Example:

```js
var array = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6','a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10','a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14', 'a15', 'a16', 'a17', 'a18', 'a19', 'a20', 'a21', 'a22', 'a23'];
```

Expected outcome (inserted b & c at position 2nd & 9th ):

> ['a1', '**b1**', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6','a7', '**c1**', 'a8', 'a9', '**b2**', 'a10','a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14', 'a15', '**c2**', 'a16', 'a17', '**b3**', 'a18', 'a19', 'a20', 'a21', 'a22', 'a23'];

How to achieve the result?

Comment: Hi. What work have you done to try and solve this yourself? SO is here to help you with code that you've written. You can add code as a [mcve] to the question using the snippet tool `[<>`]` available in the edit toolbar.

Comment: use the counter to count in the loop and make the counter zero when the counter reaches 10 and repeat the process.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the array while adding elements with `Array#splice`.

```js
const array = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6','a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10','a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14', 'a15', 'a16', 'a17', 'a18', 'a19', 'a20', 'a21', 'a22', 'a23'];
const prefix = new Map([[1, 'b'], [8, 'c']]);
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const p = prefix.get(i % 10);
  if (p) array.splice(i, 0, p + Math.ceil(i / 10)), ++i;
}
console.log(array);
```